# How do I copy a website from one azure website to another (not deployment slots)?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have 2 azure websites in the same subscription and I want to copy the site from one to another. I know I can copy the entire site down to my local machine using FTP then upload the entire site, but it seems like there should be an easier way, especially considering the FTP hostname is the same for both sites.

These are not deployment slots, so I can't just swap them in the interface.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I think you can use the SiteReplicator site extension to do that. You can find it here https://www.siteextensions.net/packages/sitereplicator/.

The scm site can be found at URL_OF_Your_SITE.scm.azurewebsites.net and then go to Site Extensions to install it if it's not visible in the portal under the Site Extensions gallery.

Comment: According to the documentation, the replication happens automatically when it detects changes within the site/wwwroot folder of the source site.  Will it also do an initial replication? Also, how do I tell it which is the "source" and which is the "target". Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can use backup/restore feature. That will create a ZIP file from your site, store it in your storage account (including configuration serialized to XML) and then you can restore to a different/new site. In the end it is basically copying files around anyway, but maybe it is fancier than doing it manually through FTP. Another benefit is that also the website's configuration is copied around. This is one time thing only though. It is not clear from your question whether you want to do copy one time or periodically (that I would suggest the site replicator mentioned in the other response here).

Some links which might help:
Backup - http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-backup/
Restore - http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-restore/